# Android cardview, change background color with switch listener

Tags: java, android

I have a cardview with a switch inside. When the switch is on, I want to change the background color of the card to green, when is off(by default it is) instead is red.
I also need to save the switch state locally, so when I open the app again, it remain in the last position it was.
I don't know if it's ok doing all the code for that in the adapter..I'm using 2 fragment, and the cardview is inside one of them, in a listview.
I think I have to use

`// paidSwitch is the switch in the cardview
paidSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            paidCard.setCardBackgroundColor(??? I need to get my R.color.green value here);`

This code is inside the getView method in the adapter class.
Each cardview in the list has it's own switch. I attach a picture of the fragments, so it's easier to understand.
ps. How can I reduce the size(screen size) of the picture when I post some photo here?
[image]

Comment: "How can I reduce the size(screen size) of the picture when I post some photo here? " - [Have a look at this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253403/2850651). Aside from that, what are you asking, exactly?

Comment: Thank's for the link..I'm asking how to change the background color of my cardview using a switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
    final int greenBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.my_red_color);
    final int redBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.my_green_color);
    switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b){
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(greenBackgroundColor);
            }
            else{
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(redBackgroundColor);
            }

        }
    });
```

And set the default card background with :

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't change the color..maybe because I don't pass any position of the list? If I write cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.green(position)); it change to grey(I don't know why, but at least it change)

Comment: I have experienced issues with changing background color of CardView, usuallly I implement a Layout on the specific area of card I need to change the color, and then setBackgroundColor for that Layout

Comment: @Nicola try to set a static color and see if it changes `cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`

Comment: @B.M I understood the problem...I set the backgroundtint in the xml file, and the color switch didn't work. I need to understand one more things..If I cannot use the xml to set the default color, what could I do?

Comment: @Nicola not sure i have understood the question but can use all the static colors available on `Color` class, like : `Color.red` and `Color.green`.. ect, like the example on my comment above

Comment: @B.M my question Is: how Can I set a default background color for the cardview? Because if I use "backgroundTint" in the xml, then the code you post above doesn't work.

Comment: @Nicola you can use `app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"`for example

Comment: @Nicola glad it helped, i will update the answer to be completed

Answer (score 0):

To save state locally, you can use SharedPrefrences or [Paper](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper) library. I personally prefer Paper.

You can use it like so

```
//Init Paper
Paper.init(this);

//save switch state
Paper.book().write("key1", "value1");
Paper.book().write("key2", "value2");

// key being the switch Indentifier, value being the state of the specific switch

//save switch state
String value1 = Paper.book().read("key1");
String value2= Paper.book().read("key2");

//delete all saved record
Paper.book().destroy();
```

EDIT --

This logic of Saving the state can be implemented after the if-else of the onCheckedChanged, like so

```
if (isChecked){
    //line of code to change color
   ...
}
else{
    //line of code to change color
   ...
}

 //line of code to save state
 Paper.book().write("position", isChecked);
```

This logic of Reading the state & Setting to switches can be implemented in onResume (and onCreate too, if needed) , like so

```
paidSwitchAtPosition.setChecked(Paper.book().read("position"));
```